# mongodb No server chosen by com.mongodb.async.client.ClientSessionHelper error

Tags: mongodb, scala, client, driver

I want to connect mongodb by use scala , but I got error: `No server chosen by com.mongodb.async.client.ClientSessionHelper$1@8c3b9d from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=10.74.155.54:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out`

Here is some version info:
- mongodb: 4.0.3
- scala: 2.11.12

This is my `build.sbt` file

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.mongodb" % "bson" % "3.8.2",
    "org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver-core" % "3.8.2",
    "org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver-async" % "3.8.2",
    "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.4.2",
    "org.mongodb.scala" % "mongo-scala-bson_2.11" % "2.4.2"
)
```

I code like this:

```
val mongoClient: MongoClient =  MongoClient("mongodb://xxxx/mydb")
val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb")
val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("test")
```

I just want to connect a `standalone mongod`, Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `"mongodb://xxxx/mydb"` to `"mongodb://10.74.155.54"` and make sure the database is reachable from wherever you run the Scala app (no firewall etc).